# ActiveAdmin / Formtastic sortable has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I may be missing something fundamental here, but I can't seem to get ActiveAdmin to work with a sortable has_many through relationship, with the ability to create new records.

So given the following models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_videos
  has_many :videos, through: :user_videos

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_videos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :videos

  ...
end

class UserVideo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :video

end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_videos
  has_many :users, through: :user_videos

  ...
end
```

(I admit I'm throwing `accepts_nested_attributes_for` around somewhat in the hopes that something may work)

And Active Admin setup goes something like this (WIP of course):

```
f.inputs "User" do
  f.has_many :user_videos, heading: 'Videos', sortable: :order, allow_destroy: true, new_record: 'New Record' do |v|
    v.inputs for: :video do |video|
      video.input :video_url
    end
  end
  f.has_many :videos, heading: 'Videos', new_record: 'New Video' do |v|
    v.input :video_url
  end
end

f.actions
```

The first `has_many` on the `:user_videos` association does not seem to render any inputs. If there are records there, I can see that `video.input :video_url` is actually returning an `li` tag with `label` and `input`, however nothing gets rendered to the page. For new records the whole `v.inputs` bit does not get run (do I need to create the child records somehow there first?).

The second `has_many` will work in that you'll be able to add records, and update existing records, however it's impossible to sort as the `order` column is on the `UserVideos` model. I include this more as illustration than anything.

If anyone has any pointers for this, they would be most appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody seemed interested in tackling this, I took another approach - rather than trying to get ActiveAdmin / Formtastic to work with the existing model structure, I added getters and setters for the necessary field on the intersection model.

```
class UserVideo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video

  validates_with VideoValidator

  def video_url
    self.video = Video.create if video.nil?
    self.video.video_url
  end

  def video_url=(video_url)
    self.video = Video.create if video.nil?
    self.video.video_url = video_url
    # Video url is set via Active Admin, AA will not call save on the video as it does not realise it's changed
    self.video.save! if video.present? and video.valid?
  end

end
```

Doing this meant that Active Admin did not need to know about the Video model, and could just operate on the UserVideo model:

```
  f.has_many :user_videos, heading: 'Videos', sortable: :order, allow_destroy: true, new_record: 'New Record' do |v|
    v.input :video_url, :hint => (v.object.video.embed_code unless v.object.nil? or v.object.video.nil?)
  end
```

If anyone has an actual solution rather than a work around, I'd love to hear it, but otherwise this is a possible solution for anyone searching for an answer to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

WHOA! I know I am late to the party, but this is a perfect opportunity to utilize the [:delegate method](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)!

Your UserVideo class would look something like this

```
class UserVideo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video

  validates_with VideoValidator

  delegate :video_url, :video_url=, to: :video
end
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Delegate would not work because the getter and setter are creating the video if it doesn't exist.